# Удалить строку из бд и таблицы при нажатии кнопки

Tags: php, html

немного не понимаю почему при нажатии кнопки запись из бд не удаляется

```
<tbody>
            <?php
            header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            require_once ('connection.php');
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
                <tr>
                    <form action="index.php" method="post" role = "form">
                        <td><?php echo $row['vk_id'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['qqqq'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['wwww'];?></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Изменить</button></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="submitDeleteBtn" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" required></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            <?php }
            require_once ("delete_tub.php");
            ?>
            </tbody>
```

код удаления строки delete_tub.php[image: введите сюда описание изображения]:

```
require_once ('connection.php');

if(isset($_GET['submitDeleteBtn']))
{
    $id = $_GET['submitDeleteBtn'];

    $query ="DELETE FROM botadmin WHERE id = '$id'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: fuuu - html и php  в одном файле - хотя бы через шаблонизатор вынесли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, вы посылаете форму методом POST а читаете параметр из $_GET.

<s>Во-вторых, кнопки - не поля для ввода, какой смысл отправлять их вместе с данными?</s>.

В-третьих, почему для кнопки *Изменить* вы используете тег <button>, а для кнопки *Удалить* тег <input>? Сами то не путаетесь?

**UPDATE**

Если я делаю две кнопки с одинаковым именем:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="edit">Сохранить</button>
<button name="action" value="delete">Удалить</button>
```

Результатом формы помимо текстовых полей будет action "edit" или "delete", в зависимости от того, какую кнопку нажали. Это не похоже на стандартное поведение, требует проверки во всех браузерах отдельно. Про это поведение не могу ничего найти в стандарте. Хотя в [примере №20](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-readonly-attribute) это явно используется. Каюсь.

Comment: Добрый день,
Ваш ответ очень помог, большое спасибо!

Comment: @ATeV1L__ ответ исправлен немного!